# How can I set an image's src to the src of another image on the same web page with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image that I am trying to update the source of to the source of another image on the same page. How can this be done using jQuery?

What I have tried:

```
$('#existingLogoImage').attr('src',$('#currentLogoPreview').attr.src());
```

What I have found that works:

```
$('#existingLogoImage').attr('src',$('#currentLogoPreview').attr('src'));
```

Comment: could you post a fiddle showing your attempts?

Comment: Tell us what you've tried.

Comment: Not sure of the reason for the down votes, as the question is rather straight forward, and I have not found any other questions on SO that this question may duplicate, which is why I have asked the question the way I have. Sorry for not posting examples. In fact, examples are what I was looking for.

Comment: So if you found the working solution, what is your question?

Comment: My question remains as it has been clearly stated above. At least now when someone is looking to do what I needed to do they will have a resource with the three current examples and other examples that may be posted in the future, which is what SO is for. Right? Some elitist seem as if they may disagree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be straight forward, you can use [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to both set and get the source

```
$('#image_to_set').prop('src', $('#image_to_get').prop('src'));
```

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("img1").src=document.getElementById("img2").src;
```